# open directory with a variable bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, variables, cd

I'am reading in a variable that will contain a version of a certain file (Ex.: V1.0.10) by the following command.

```
read Version
```

and there is a possibility that that variable contains dots and I remove them by the next command:

```
New_Version=`echo $Version | sed -e 's/\.//g'`
```

but if I use this variable later on in the script, nothing changes at this variable, and I just use the cd command:

```
cd /data/group/$New_Version
```

or

```
cd /data/group/"$New_Version"
```

Then the error: No such file or directory... : line ...: cd:/data/group/V1010.
I double checked, the files exists, the name is correct but he doesn't find or recognize the directory?

What am I doing wrong?

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Comment: what's the value of $New_Version? is it really V10101 or spaces or spl characters around?

Comment: It can also be a different combination but nu spaces and no spl characters

Comment: could it be a problem on permissions? Maybe you cannot access such dir

Comment: try this  `cd "/data/group/$New_Version"`

Comment: ls -ld /data/group/$New_Version ; test -d /data/group/$New_Version ...... As which user are you running the script?

Comment: I am running as normal user but checked it as root and same problem cd "/data/group/$New_Version" doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you just create a small 3-4 lines script which does just these things that you mentioned, and check if it reproduces the problem? If so, update your question with that small script.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `set -x` at the top of this script to log (to stderr) the exact commands run by the shell, **including all hidden characters**. If your input file includes something like a `CRLF`, for instance, that would result in what you're describing here, as the CR would be a hidden `$'\r'` character at the end of the directory name.

Comment: Thank you very much Charles Duffy! It was a hidden character!

Comment: cd /data/group/$New_Version^M went visible after i did cat -v and my filename. I deleted it and it worked perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE: The OP says that the problem was a hidden character in his input. This answer does not describe how to solve that problem. Nonetheless, the OP has marked this answer as accepted. See the comments of Charles Duffy for the actual solution to the OP's problem.

Caveat: I am taking everything in your problem description literally, which leads to the answer below. If you provide examples of the strings that will be passed through `$Version` it would help clarify the issue.

---

As I understand it you're reading in the full path of a file in your variable with `read Version`. Now if you say `echo $Version` you should get `/path/to/foo.bar`.

I don't think you'd want to `cd` into the file `/path/to/foo.bar`. You'll get an error: `Not a directory`, because it's a file, not a directory.

Now, consider what `sed -e /\.//g` will do to the pathname.

```
echo "/path/to/foo.bar" | sed -e '/\.//g'
/path/to/foobar
```

Does `/path/to/foobar` actually exist? No, because `foo.bar` was a file. You'll get an error: `No such file or directory`, because the `foobar` directory does not exist.

If I understand what you are trying to do, you are trying to extract the directory that contains the file specified by `$Version`. The command `dirname /path/to/foo.bar` will return `/path/to`. So you want to set `New_version=$( dirname "$Version" )`, at which point you should be able to `cd $New_version`.

P.S. Make sure `$Version` is reading in an absolute path name, not a relative name, so that it's independent of where you run the script from.

Comment: `New_version = foo` is **not the same** as `New_version=foo`; the former runs `New_version` as a command, with `=` as its first argument. (`New_version= foo` is a completely separate thing, which runs `foo` as a command with `New_version` exported as an empty string in the environment). Whitespace matters in shell; don't use too much of it.

Comment: Hah! indeed it will. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but I dont read in a directory only V1.0.10. But by the help of Charles Duffy (See up) I could find the problem!

Comment: See up to have the awnser! It was a hidden character, you can check this by cat -v filename.

Comment: I don't think you should have marked this answer as accepted if it wasn't really the solution.